# Compare column to an array of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have being trying to achieve something like this in laravel but so far, it has not being possible.

If it's possible, please someone should help

```
->where("note_id","!=",array('1','2','3'))->first();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What was your expected result if you tried `whereNotIn` and didn't get it? This is what you need, so probably you need more constraints or clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereNotIn`, as explained in the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) documentation.

```
Model::whereNotIn('note_id', array(1, 2, 3))->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this before but didn't get the expected output. The query is suppose to fetch data where note_id not equal to 1 or 2 or 3 but it is not working that way

Comment: Did you write it as `array(1, 2, 3)` or as `array('1', '2', '3')`?

Comment: @deczo Ye, I guess it would.

Comment: It should,  I did something like `$notify="1, 2, 3"` then `array ($ notify)`. The query work but return d very first element in the table with note_id= 1 which is not suppose.

Comment: No, that (`array('1, 2, 3')`)is just plain wrong. It really should be `array(1, 2, 3)`, but `array('1', '2', '3')` should work as well.

Comment: thanks, I found out that the ID's are being passed as string instead of an array. Thanks once more, I appreciate.